# multiply matrix with vector

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have the matrix like this

```
Table1 = [A B ; C D ; E F]
```

and the vector:

```
V = [a ; b ; c]
```

How to get the multiplication of second column of matrix M to get the answer as below?

```
ans =[aB ; bD; cF]
```

Currently I'm doing,

```
Table1;
d=length(Table1(:,2));
for i = 1:d
   ans(i,:) = sum(Table1(i,2)) .* V';
 end
```

The only way I can think would be using loops but I couldn't get the answer as I wish. Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 5):

Hi If you really want `ans =[aB ; bD; cF]`. You are looking for the elementwise product of the second column with the vector.

THat would be:

```
product = Table1(:,2).*V;
```

or if you want the same order (normally that shouldn't matter but who knows)

```
product = V.*Table1(:,2);
```

Table1(:,2) adresses the second column. And the dot (.) means elementwise.

Otherwise MATLAB can process Matrix multiplication and others just as you would write them on paper.

Comment: @LuisMendo Well mathematically you could have sth like gradient (d/dx, d/dy, d/dz). So by multiplying it first you get (d/dx x, d/dy y, d/dz z) or by multiplying it second you would have (x d/dx, y d/dy, z d/dz). Which would change a lot because you would have to do additional derivation. Because I am a physist I have to take sth like that into account :D

Comment: Oh, I see. I've always considered that "gradient after/before" thing as a notation trick, rather than a real product, but you're right. In this case, perhaps `.*` could be overloaded into something non-commutative

Answer (score 0):

If you know that you want to multiply the second number of every vector

```
Table1 = [A B ; C D ; E F]
```

you can use the `downsample` command

```
newTable=downsample(Table1, n) % with n=2 or the step you want

newTable= [B ; D; F]
V = [a ; b ; c]
```

then you can use the multiplying vectors to get your results

```
x = newTable.*V
x =[B*a; D*b ; F*c]
```

Comment: You could easily just use `Table1(:,n)` instead of using `downsample()`. ALso he doesn't want to multiply a constant to each value but a vector. so your resulting `x` is wrong your code (if a=V in OP) is still right (except the double use of a)

Comment: @Minion you are correct i overlooked it , i will alter the answer

Comment: and you have a typo in newTable (2nd code block) you have `D, F` but need `D; F`